# How to tell to use the Windows recovery partition to install?

Tags: installation

My disk partitions are like this :
on /dev/sda

/dev/sda1    ntfs  RECOVERY    13.1 GiB
/dev/sda2    ntfs  WIN8        142 GiB
/dev/sda3    ntfs  data        143 Gib

The recovery partition is for Vista so I'd like to install ubuntu on that. In simple mode, the installer only offer to use /dev/sda2. In advanced mode, it shows the 3 partitions, is it enough to select sda1 and click 'Install Now' ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In advanced mode, if you choose /dev/sda1/, it should format /dev/sda1 and install Ubuntu where the recovery used to be.

Comment: Should work just fine, you may want to "format" it ext4 though. (The installer will almost certainly do this for you)